# Lambdas syntax error with if

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Let's take as an example with this simple dataset:

```
example_set  = pd.DataFrame(data = {"dirr":[1,0,-1,-1,1,-1,0], 
                                    "value": [125,130,80,8,150,251,18], 
                                    "result":[np.NaN for _ in range(7)]})
```

The following line returns `error:invalid syntax`

```
example_set["result"].apply(lambda x : example_set["value"]if x["dirr"]==1)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Please do not come up with solution of how to do it without `lambda`: This is only a super simplified example that I made up to isolate my problem.

Comment: @EdChum Please read the question fully: *Please do not come up with solution of how to do it without lambdas: This is only a super simplified example that I made up to isolate my problem.*

Comment: `.apply(lambda x : example_set["value"] if x["dirr"]==1 else x)`?

Comment: @MYGz this returns another error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the `else` return value in the lambda statement:

```
In [7]:
example_set['result'] = example_set.apply(lambda x: x['value'] if x['dirr'] == 1 else x['result'], axis = 1)
example_set

Out[7]:
   dirr  result  value
0     1   125.0    125
1     0     NaN    130
2    -1     NaN     80
3    -1     NaN      8
4     1   150.0    150
5    -1     NaN    251
6     0     NaN     18
```

Your attempt:

```
example_set["result"].apply(lambda x : example_set["value"]if x["dirr"]==1)
```

lacked the `else` return value in essence, also you needed `x['value']` not the whole df, using the whole df yields a strange and undesirable return result even if the statement was corrected:

```
In [14]:
example_set.apply(lambda x: example_set['value'] if x['dirr'] == 1 else example_set['result'], axis = 1)

Out[14]:
       0      1     2    3      4      5     6
0  125.0  130.0  80.0  8.0  150.0  251.0  18.0
1    NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2    NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
3    NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
4  125.0  130.0  80.0  8.0  150.0  251.0  18.0
5    NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
6    NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Also, you can't access corresponding values of other columns if you `.apply()` on a single column. True?

Comment: @MYGz yes that's correct, by definition it would call the `Series` version which has no `axis` param, only the `DataFrame.apply` version has `axis` param